# appendChild Possibly Deleting Element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple to-do list application JavaScript. I have written up JavaScript to basically take the value from an input element and pass it into a few functions.

**I created a live example on CodePen, which you may view here: http://cdpn.io/hnBmD**

***Edit: Code also located below?***

It seems like appendChild could possibly be deleting the "li" node that the parent function is creating? May someone please give me a reasonable explanation to this?

Note: I do have the JavaScript in a separate file and it is being loaded right before the ending body tags.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
 <p><input type="text" id="inItemText" autofocus><button type="submit" id="submitButton">+</button></p>
</form>
<ul id="toDoList">
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Defining nodes.
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
// Once "enter" is pressed or click event is triggered, execute the function.
// The function below is basically checking the value of the input, to make sure the value is empty. If it isn't, it passes the value and the "ul" element node into the addNewItem function.
submitButton.onclick = function(){
      var itemText = inItemText.value;
      if (itemText == "" || itemText == " ") {
        return false;
      } else {
        addNewItem(document.getElementById("toDoList"), itemText);
      }
}
// Once the parameters are passed. This basically creates a "li" element, applies the value of the input element into the innerText of the "li" element created and then appends the "ul" with the "li" we just created. Also, it resets the value of the input so we can enter another checklist item in.
function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = itemText;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
    itemText = inItemText.value = "";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `appendChild` should never remove anything, all it does is add the new node.

Comment: @AkinkunleAllen: I provided a link to CodePen that has the code in it.

Comment: @Barmar: That's what I thought, but I have no idea how my new nodes are being automatically removed after the function finishes what it needs to do.

Comment: We prefer code to be shown here, so readers don't have to go to a third-party site to understand the question.

Comment: @Barmar: Okay, code added. I figured you all would prefer to see it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `false` from the `onclick` function after it calls `addNewItem`. Otherwise it will submit the form, which reloads the page.

```
submitButton.onclick = function(){
      var itemText = inItemText.value;
      if (itemText == "" || itemText == " ") {
        return false;
      } else {
        addNewItem(document.getElementById("toDoList"), itemText);
        return false;
      }
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHlAp)

Or more simply:

```
submitButton.onclick = function(){
    var itemText = inItemText.value.trim();
    if (itemText !== "" || itemText == " ") {
        addNewItem(document.getElementById("toDoList"), itemText);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or, as one of the comments suggested, get rid of the form, then there's nothing to submit.

Comment: Ah! Thank you Barmar! Can you go more into detail about this "return false" and the proper usage for it? I have heard many-a-things about why it is bad, but haven't heard too many reasons on why it is good.

Comment: `return false` is used in an event handler to prevent the default action. In this case, the default action of clicking on a submit button is to submit the form, and you want to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the **form** if not necessary or just prevent the default form submit action.

```
submitButton.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemText = inItemText.value;
        if (itemText == "" || itemText == " ") {
            return false;
        } else {
            addNewItem(document.getElementById("toDoList"), itemText);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `button` element in your HTML has a `type` attribute of `submit`. When its click event is triggered, the default action is performed which is to submit the form. You need to prevent this default behaviour.

```
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

submitButton.onclick = function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent it from submitting
  var itemText = inItemText.value;
  if (itemText == "" || itemText == " ") {
    return false;
  } else {
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("toDoList"), itemText);
  }
}

function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
 var listItem = document.createElement("li");
 listItem.innerText = itemText;
 list.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Can you tell me the difference between this and "return false"? Also, why did you add the "e" parameter to the function? Thank you!

Comment: @AaronBrewer They both will prevent the default action of the event. Event handler functions are passed an Event Object as argument. It give details about the event. `e` is just a reference to they object in the object.